# How to get current filename in dojo

Tags: javascript, dojo

How can I get the current file name I'm in, using dojo.
I have a javascript file and my break point is within that file. I want to know the file name.
and using dojo or javascipt I want to get the name of this file

Any Help will be highly appreciated
Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using AMD (Dojo 1.7+) you can get the module ID of the current module from the special `module` module:

```js
define([ 'module' ], function (module) {
  console.log(module.id);
});
```

If using legacy Dojo modules, the filename of the script currently being executed is never provided and cannot be retrieved in a cross-browser way because they are loaded using XHR and `eval`.

Answer (score 0):

There is an example of that in dojo/tests/_base/loader/moduleIds.js :

```
function get(mid, refmod){
    return require.getModuleInfo(mid, refmod, require.packs, require.modules, "../../dojo/", require.mapProgs, require.pathsMapProg, 1);
}
```

I tried the following in one of my modules :

```
require.getModuleInfo("my/Module", null, require.packs, require.modules, "../../dojo/", require.mapProgs, require.pathsMapProg, 1).url
```

This resolved the path to the javascript file that contains my module code...

This works too :

```
require.modules["my/module"].url
```

Comment: Those properties aren’t intended to be accessed by end-user code and are only available when the `dojo-publish-privates` has-flag is truthy. They are for debugging, testing, and building.

Comment: Is there a way to resolve a module name to an URL without being in debug mode ?